# Rigorous definition of Cartesian product

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Recall the 'rigorous' definition of the Cartesian product $A\times B$ is the set of all functions $\phi:\{1,2\}\to A\cup B$ such that $\phi(1)\in A$ and $\phi(2)\in B$. To show there is a bijective correspondence between the sets $A_1\space\times ...\times\space A_n$ and $\left(A_1\space\times...\times\space A_{n-1}\right)\times A_n$, I'd like to appeal to this definition.

Now I know the bijection is 'clearly' $\left(a_1,...,a_n\right)\to\left(\left(a_1,...,a_{n-1}\right), a_n\right)$, but I'd like to interpret the bijection in terms of the definition first, because it's not actually clear what $\left(\left(a_1,...,a_{n-1}\right), a_n\right)$ even means.

So first, $A_1\space\times ...\times\space A_n$ is clearly the set of all functions $f:\{1,...,n\}\to A_1\space\cup...\cup\space A_n$ such that $f(i)\in A_i $. To form an element of $\left(A_1\space\times...\times\space A_{n-1}\right)\times A_n$, we first need to form an element of $A=A_1\space\times...\times\space A_{n-1}$, which is the set of all functions $g:\{1,...,n-1\}\to A_1\space\cup...\cup\space A_{n-1}$ such that $g(i)\in A_i$. Then from the first paragraph, $A\times A_n$ is the set of all functions $h:\{1,2\}\to A\space\cup A_n$ such that $h(1)\in A$ and $h(2)\in A_n$. This is where I'm concerned since the function $h$ is sending elements of its domain to different types of objects.

So $h(1)$ is not an element of any single $A_i$ but is a $n-1$ tuple or an arbitrary function $g$. However, $h(2)$ is just any element of $A_n$. I guess this makes the notation $\left(\left(a_1,...,a_{n-1}\right), a_n\right)$ make sense since $h$ consists of two coordinates, the first coordinate value being a function and the second coordinate value being an element of $A_n$.

Is this thinking correct?

Comment: $h(1)$ is a function with domain $\{1,\ldots,n-1\}$ (and codomain $\cup_{i=1}^{n-1}A_i$) with the property that $h(1)(i)\in A_i$ for $i=1,\ldots,n-1$. This is an example of "currying".

Comment: Nothing in the definition of function precludes different values having different "types". But you need to be clear what your primitives are. Here you're seemingly taking function as primitive and defining pair in terms of it, although the opposite is commonly done using something like the Kuratowski pair and defining a function as a set of pairs (etc.).

Comment: Your take on the rigorous definition of Cartesian products is over-simplified. The usual set-theoretic treatment of $n$-tuples is more clunky: you first define a notation of ordered pairing, e.g., the Kuratowski pairing, then you use that to define functions as a certain kind of sets of ordered pairs and then you use those to define $n$-tuples for arbitrary $n$. However, I don't know of a better way if you start from a set theory with a minimalist vocabulary comprising only the membership relation.